# Как с помощью регулярных выражений проверить, что в строке дано число или просто пустой символ в c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, текст

У меня есть строка, которую нужно проверить на корректность. Нужно, чтобы было в строке перед точкой было либо число(количество цифр может быть в пределах от 1 до 3), либо пустая область. Вот пример тех строк, которые должны быть определены как правильные:

```
string str = "word 10.5 something else";
string str2 = "word .5 something else";
```

Какое выражение для этого нужно использовать?

Я пробовал такие выражения:

```
new Regex(@"(*.?)\s\b[\d+\|]\b\.\d*\s"); 
new Regex(@"(*.?)\b[\s\d+\|\s]\b\.\d*\s");
new Regex(@"(*.?)\s[\d\|]*\.\d*\s");
```

и некоторые другие, но они не либо не работают, либо работают неправильно.

Comment: Вам нужно проверить пробел затем 0-3 цифр и затем точку, при этом не забудьте точку заэкранировать, а цифры оформить группой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем так сложно? По вашему описанию должно быть достаточно такого:

```
\s\d{0,3}\.
```

Проверка на [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NzF4M3/2).